# lengthy “Description” in Facebook Share Dialog box are not showing completely

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, facebook-apps, facebook-ui

```
FB.UI(
    {
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',  
      description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface 
                    with users Dialogs provide a simple,consistent interface for applications to,
                    interface with users.'
      link: 'http://www.slstop.com/',
      picture: 'http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/media/p/2/000/0b3/027/17c9231.png',
    }
    )
```

Facebook share dialog lengthy  “Description” are not showing completely 
     According to the above code I have assigned a lengthy paragraph to the “Description” 
    variable, and it is showing completely after pressing the “Share” button, but Once 
    the “Publish” button on the Dialog box, when the post appear in Facebook timeline, 
    the “Description” part is not shown fully(only showing two lines of description).

```
Is there any solution to show the lengthy  “Description” completely?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Facebook's news feed decides how much of the description to show and this is not configurable or something you have control over when making your API calls

You should make the description relevant, brief, and put the most important information first if you're concerned that not all of your message will be shown